# Working with 14-bit data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, bit

My current workflow involves dealing with 8-bit resolution data, written in 16-bit format and 64-bit format. For example:

```
b = np.fromfile(file, dtype='uint8')
data1 = b[:2].view(np.int16)
data2 = b[2:10].view(np.int64)
# alternative: struct.unpack
```

I have just received 14-bit resolution data - what would be an appropriate similar approach to load this data, since there are no 14-bit types available?

---

**Edit**: 
Answered in the comments - thank you honza_p.

Read them as 16-bit and shift 2 bits.

Comment: Are the stored data really packed using 14 bits per item? Regardless of the 14bit resolution, I would expect them to be stored in 16bit format. At least this was the case when we had 14bit data.

Comment: I'm not sure how they are actually saved. So you loaded them as 16bit, and processed them as 16bit, or discarded/shifted 2 bits? And those 2 extra bits are usually part of the next datapoint or just garbage?

Comment: I would presume them to be 0. Try to load the data as 16bit and you will see if what you get makes sense (perhaps multiples of 4s or values in the range of 0..16383)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think one of you two should add that as an answer. @honza_p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as an answer in case comments disappear.

> Read them as 16-bit and shift 2 bits.